# Grep number words above 10 programmatically

Tags: grep

I have written a long thesis (in latex) and need to change all numbers above 10 from written words to numerals (eg thirteen to 13, twenty to 20).

The bsd-games package contains the programme numbers, which turns numerals into digits eg:

> >number -l 1234
>
> one thousand two hundred thirty-four

and I can get a sequence of numbers from say 10:1000 using seq:

> >seq 10 1000

Now all I need to do is grep all my latex files (*.tex) for the number words (above 10), so I know where to find the offending number-words, without having to read through the whole thesis!

So to be clear what I'm asking: **grep a text file to find all written number words between 10 and 1000**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `number`.  A "number in words" greater that 9 is going to contain at least one of "ten", "eleven", ... "nineteen", "twenty", "ninety", "hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion" and ... stop when it gets too silly.  That is only twenty something words.  You can easily enter them by hand on the `grep` command line.